# Org-babel-mermaid: image file not found

Tags: org-babel

I am new to Emacs. I have tried to set up ob-mermaid on my system. From what I can see, Emacs seems to be evaluating the code fine when running a quick test, but no image file is generated. I would very much appreciate any prompts for resolving this issue. In the following I will describe the steps I took to set this up and test it on my system. I am using Linux Mint and GNU Emacs:

1. `M-x package-install`: `ob-mermaid`
2. On the Linux command line I entered:

```
npm install mermaid.cli
./node_modules/.bin/mmdc -h
```

[source1](https://github.com/mermaidjs/mermaid.cli)

3. I then added the following to myinit.org ([source2](https://github.com/arnm/ob-mermaid)):

```
#+begin_src emacs-lisp
(setq ob-mermaid-cli-path "/home/tiberius/node_modules/.bin/mmdc")
  (org-babel-do-load-languages
   'org-babel-load-languages
   '((mermaid . t)
     (scheme . t)))
#+end_src
```

Initially, I had also included `(your-other-langs . t)`, as stated in [source2](https://github.com/arnm/ob-mermaid). However, this threw an error, so I removed it, as I suspect that "your-other-langs" has to be replaced by the names of actual programming languages, such as `(emacs-lisp . t)` etc.

4. I created an org file with the following text to test the new feature [source3](https://github.com/arnm/ob-mermaid) and then ran this using C-c C-c respectively I tried to export it using C-c C-e RB. Results as well as an export file are generated, but without the desired image:

```
#+begin_src mermaid :file test.png
sequenceDiagram
 A-->B: Works!
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
[[file:test.png]]
```

Output in the message buffer:

```
Evaluate this mermaid code block on your system? (y or n) y
executing Mermaid code block...
/home/tiberius/node_modules/.bin/mmdc -i /tmp/babel-fgS8pc/mermaid-XqxJeu -o /home/tiberius/Documents/Research/Projects/Notes/test.png
Wrote /tmp/babel-fgS8pc/ob-input-nhhHiy
Code block evaluation complete.
```

A [similar case](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/dfm22m/novice_question_orgbabelmermaid_outputs_an_image/) has been reported, but it's different from my situation in that an error message was generated (node command not found). Given that I am still a newbie, I may well have missed something, so any hints would be much appreciated.

Comment: "... I suspect that "your-other-langs" has to be replaced by the names of actual programming languages, such as (emacs-lisp . t) etc." - your supsicion is correct.

Comment: Did you notice the warning? `Warning

    Development has been moved to https://github.com/mermaid-js/mermaid-cli

    The mermaid.cli NPM package is no longer being updated and is very out-of-date. Please use the @mermaid-js/mermaid-cli NPM package instead.`

Comment: Thank you. I did notice this, but only after I had installed it and then I wasn't sure how exactly to remove it again, given that I set up something in `node_modules`. Would a simple `npm uninstall mermaid.cli` be sufficient?